# Tkinter button event binding in another file

Tags: python, class, tkinter, events

I'm making a simple decimal to binary converter and I have some problems with Tkinter events.

I have a file `gui.py` which stores all the graphical design and `events.py` which is the file for interactive events.

In my app i have a button that is supposed to be a convert validation- you click it, it starts the converter code and the value is being inserted in to the label. In this case I have to use events.

As the button is in the another file (`gui.py`), I put it in the class. In the `events.py` I defined the event and the event handler but I'm obviously missing something.

File with the graphical design (`gui.py`)

```
import tkinter

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("Conv")
window.geometry("200x150")
window.resizable(False, False)

TitleLabel = tkinter.Label(
    text = "Decimal to Binary converter",
    fg = "black"
)
TitleLabel.pack()

DecimalLabel = tkinter.Label(
    text = "Decimal number",
    fg = "black"
)
DecimalLabel.pack()

DecimalEntry = tkinter.Entry(

)
DecimalEntry.pack()

class ConvertButtonDiv:

    ConvertButton = tkinter.Button(
        text = "Convert!",
    )
    ConvertButton.pack()

BinaryLabel = tkinter.Label(
    text = "Binary number",
    fg = "black"
)
BinaryLabel.pack()

BinaryEntry = tkinter.Entry(

)
BinaryEntry.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

File with the events

```
import tkinter 
window = tkinter.Tk()

def Button_Click (event):
    print("This works!")
"don't know what to enter".bind("", Button_Click)
```

Any ideas or solutions?

Comment: You don't need to put the creation of button inside a class (actually you use class in a wrong way).  Just `import events` and add `command=events.Button_Click` to `Button(...)` inside `gui.py`.  Also you should not call `window = tkinter.Tk()` inside `events.py` and need to change `def Button_Click(event)` to `def Button_Click(event=None)`.

Comment: Okay, made some changes. 

`gui` file
`from events import Button_Click` this imports the function from the `events` file.

`
ConvertButton = tkinter.Button(
    text = "Convert!",
    command=Button_Click
)
ConvertButton.pack()
`
And the events file

`
def Button_Click():
    print("It works!")`

It works, but let's say I want to insert the text to the `BinaryEntry`. How do I do it?

Comment: Then you need to pass `DecimalEntry` and `BinaryEntry` to `Button_Click()` function as arguments.

Comment: Okay, I tried many solutions (also this one you said to do), but I can't get rid of the circular import error. I don't know how to eliminate this with leaving this two files importing each other. 

The situation is:

in the `events.py` I wrote the `Button_Click` function. Then I import it in the `gui.py` by doing this- `from events import Button_Click`. In the `events.py` I have to import the `BinaryEntry` to insert the value into it. 

This causes circular import, but I don't know how to eliminate it.

Comment: No you don't need to import `BinaryEntry` inside `events.py`.  Just pass `BinaryEntry` as an argument of `Button_Click()`, like `def Button_Click(decimal_entry, binary_entry)`.  Then call it like `command=lambda: Button_Click(DecimalEntry, BinaryEntry)`.

Comment: Okay, thanks. What does this `lambda` thing do?

Comment: `lambda` is anonymous function.